# Theorem proof Need Clarity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

[image]

I don't understand the part where it says:
$x - y$ $= a^{(-1)} (s - t)m$

Where did the a go; a inverse can't cancel it because it is not its reciprocal.

Comment: But you say "$a$ has at least one inverse, $a^{-1}"$

Comment: But the inverse is not necessarily 1/2 if a = 2. This is multiplicative modular inverse...the inverse has to be an integer as well...I think,

Comment: Is a in Zm as well?

Comment: A clearer  proof: If $ax\equiv 1\equiv ay \pmod m$ then (i).  $m|\;a(x-y)$ and (ii). $\gcd (a,m)=1$: Because   $n|m|(ax-1)\implies n|\;(ax-1)$. So if $n|m$ and $n|a$ then $n|(ax-1)$ and $n|ax$ so $n|(ax-(ax-1))=1.$.... Now  use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic: If $e|fg$ and $\gcd (e,f)=1$ then $e|g.$... Apply this to (i): $m|a(x-y)$ and $\gcd (m,a)=1$ so $m|(x-y).$ That is, $x\equiv y \pmod m. $

Answer (score 1):

Your theorem is incorrect.

Your hypothesis is "If $a$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb Z_m$".

You showed that $a(x-y)=(s-t)m$. It follows that $a(x-y) \equiv 0 \pmod m$. Multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$ and you get $x-y \equiv 0 \pmod m$. It follows that $x\equiv y \pmod m$.   You cannot conclude that $x=y$. For example

$\dfrac 12 \equiv 3 \equiv 8 \pmod 5$.

Possibly, you are not aware of the difference between $\bar x$ and $x$. If $x$ is an integer, then $\bar x$ is the set of all integers, $z$ such that
$x \equiv z \pmod m$. Correctly stated, the theorem would be

**THEOREM**$\quad$ If $\bar a$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb Z_m$, then this inverse is unique in $\mathbb Z_m$.

**Proof**$\quad$ Assume that $\bar a \bar x = \bar 1$ and $\bar a \bar y = \bar 1$ for some $\bar x, \bar y \in \mathbb Z_m$. Then 
$\bar a (\bar x - \bar y) 
 = \bar a \bar x - \bar a \bar y 
 = \bar 1 - \bar 1 = \bar 0$. Then 
$\bar x \bar a(\bar x - \bar y) 
 = \bar 1(\bar x - \bar y)
 = \bar x - \bar y$.

It follows that $\bar x = \bar y$; that is to say, $\bar a^{-1}$ is unique in 
$\mathbb Z_m$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

Since $ax\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\;m)$ and $ay\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\;m)$ so $ax\equiv ay(\textrm{mod}\;m)$ by transitivity. Now applying $a^{-1}$ we would get $x\equiv y(\textrm{mod}\;m)$. Since $x, y$ are both in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ so this implies that $x=y$.

Comment: That does not explain how x-y = a^(-1) (s-t)m is derived from:               
 a(x-y) = (s-t)m.

Comment: Yes you are right. It does not.

Comment: I am not sure the proof carries this way. $a^{-1}$ should have been applied earlier in the congruence relation.